# Add Category Descriptions to Montezuma Theme

Tags: categories

Ok, a Quick Question:

I´m using the montezuma theme and would like to add category descriptions above my category pages.

How can I do that?

I found descriptions on how to do that with other themes but not with Montezuma because it doesn´t use archive.php or category.php.

If you know how, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The WordPress [template hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Category_display) indicates that `index.php` is the template used, if  `category.php` and `archive.php` are missing.

So, you can insert your code in `index.php`, and wrap it in a [`is_category`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_category) conditional to make sure it's only executed when a category archive is being displayed:

```
<?php
    if( is_category() ) {
        // category description
    }
?>
```

Comment: Or duplicate the index, rename it to `archive.php` and adapt.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Unfortunately it isn´t showing up.

Comment: I have tried to place the code in different places.

Comment: Try to edit `montezuma/admin/default-templates/main-templates/index.php`

Comment: Thanks diggy, but that doesn´t work either. Not sure what to do now...